# GUROBI: 'Missing constraint index' when adding constraint in Python

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, integer-programming

Trying to add the following constraint in Gurobi/Python:
[image: Constraint]

**Code**

```
N_SERVERS = 5                             #number of servers
C_SERVER = [1]*N_SERVERS
N_NODES = 3                               #number of nodes
C_NODES = [2]*N_NODES    

#create model
m = Model("mip1")

#declare variables
x = m.addVars(len(C_SERVER), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name = "x")
y = m.addVars(len(C_NODES), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name = "y")
m.update()

m.addConstrs(quicksum(x[i]*C_SERVER[i] for i in range(len(x))) + quicksum(y[j]*C_NODES[j] for j in range(len(y))) == quicksum(C_SERVER)
```

I get the following error: KeyError: 'Missing constraint index'. What is the reason?

Comment: SOLVED. If anyone would have the same problem, I solved it by removing the "s" on m.addConstrs to m.addConstr as it will only generate one constraint.

Comment: Be careful: your parenthesis may be incorrect in the constraint expression.